# .swf Adobe flex not loading on website

Tags: php, html, adobe, flash

Pardon the technological terminology blunders.

A long time ago I built and compiled a flex app into a .swf.

I decided to start testing how to load this onto a website.

```
<object width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="main.swf">
    <embed src="/flash/main.swf" width="550" height="400" autoplay="true"
        loop="true" autostart="true">
    </embed>
</object>
```

However upon visiting my website, I am greeted with... nothing.

If I inpect the page source, however, and click on the src link, it works. It works meaning... well the forms and everything show up as expected.

I've a feeling I am missing something basic, or that embedding different technologies may become complicated.

This is all done on a .php page, served by fatcow, if that helps.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<object width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="/flash/main.swf">
    <embed src="/flash/main.swf" width="550" height="400" autoplay="true"
        loop="true" autostart="true">
    </embed>
</object>
```